# Where can I find the standard WIX Burn localization file?

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I'm trying to customise my WIX 3.8 Burn installer by following the instructions here: http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/

However I can't for the life of me find the en-US localisation file for Burn. Where can I get it from?

I tried the file at http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/localization however that doesn't include the right messages (eg `InstallMessage`)

Or is there a better way to customise the first page of the installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of the WiX source. You can get the latest at https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/ext/BalExtension/wixstdba/Resources or get wix38-debug.zip from https://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/115492.

Comment: Perfect, I could not find it in that source tree. Thanks